# CSS flexbox row, last row containing less items than number of columns is stretching too large

Tags: css

I have a flexbox with a bunch of items in it set to `flex-grow: 1`. These items will stretch until a new column can be formed, then all move as needed. Except, when it hits 5 columns currently there are only 3 remaining items for the last row, and they stretch to be 3 larger items than the rest and fill up the space. I have `justify-content` set to `flex-start`, but how can I get those last items to match the size of the items above them and just fit neatly into the existing columns?

I have tried setting different alignments, but the only thing that gets properly sized items is the fixed size which runs into spacing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand you want the children to fill the columns of the parent and size themselves equally, it's better to use the `grid` property, this will automatically place the children and adjust the width for you.

```css
/* CSS */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
}

/* unrelated */
.child {
  background-color: #AAA;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
  <div class="child">content here</div>
</div>
```

as in this CSS rule `repeat()` has two arguments first one to specify the number of columns and the last is to specify the width of the columns, you can put your minimum and maximum widths inside `minmax()` respectfully, just like `flex-grow: 1` `1fr` will make it stretch to fill the remaining width, also you can set the gap between children using `gap` property